# Loop through array and check which has more string length

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, and i need to get the item who has more string count.

```
Array ( [0] => stackoverflow [1] => website [2] => site )
```

Let say this is the array. I want to get the array with value "stackoverflow" because it has more string count.

How can i dot it using loop and `strlen`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way you can get it:

```
$string = ['stackoverflow', 'website', 'site'];

$l = 0;
$word = '';

    foreach($string as $str) {

        $len = strlen($str);
        if ($len > $l) {
            $word = $str;
            $l = $len;
        } 
    }

return print_r($word);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_reduce to get the longest string.

```
echo array_reduce($array, function($carry, $value)   {
    $strlen = strlen($value);
    if( $strlen > strlen( $carry)  ) {
        $carry = $value;
    }
    return $carry;
});
```